# matlab: grouping variables for observations that can be in multiple groups

Tags: matlab, grouping

I would like to use MATLAB group statistics functions (like grpstats) on data where each observation can be in multiple groups. For example, pizzas can have {'pepperoni', 'mushroom','onions'} or {'pepperoni'} or whatever and then I want group stats by topping: all of the pizzas with 'pepperoni', all of them with 'mushroom', etc.

Alternatively if you know a way to do this by hand without iterating like an idiot that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put repeated measures in different rows. For example:

```
store = repmat(cellstr(num2str((1:3)')), 3, 1);
type  = repmat({'pepperoni', 'mushrooms', 'onions'}, 3, 1);
type  = Type(:);
score = dataset({randn(9,3), 'taste', 'looks', 'price'});

data = [dataset(store, type) score];

grpstats(data(:,2:end), 'type')
```

Raw data:

```
>> data

data = 

    store      type               taste       looks       price   
    '1'        'pepperoni'        -0.19224    -0.44463    -0.50782
    '2'        'pepperoni'        -0.27407    -0.15594    -0.32058
    '3'        'pepperoni'          1.5301     0.27607    0.012469
    '1'        'mushrooms'        -0.24902    -0.26116     -3.0292
    '2'        'mushrooms'         -1.0642     0.44342    -0.45701
    '3'        'mushrooms'          1.6035     0.39189      1.2424
    '1'        'onions'             1.2347     -1.2507     -1.0667
    '2'        'onions'           -0.22963    -0.94796     0.93373
    '3'        'onions'            -1.5062    -0.74111     0.35032
```

Group stats:

```
>> grpstats(data(:,2:end), 'type')

ans = 

                 type               GroupCount    mean_taste    mean_looks    mean_price
    pepperoni    'pepperoni'        3              0.35459      -0.10817      -0.27197  
    mushrooms    'mushrooms'        3              0.09674       0.19138      -0.74791  
    onions       'onions'           3             -0.16704      -0.97992      0.072449
```

Comment: Thanks -- this obviously works. As a general solution it seems non-ideal to me for a couple of reasons: if you /don't/ filter by group you have to remember to collapse the repeats, and it can take up a lot of memory if the observations belong to many groups. But it may be the best cheap solution.

Comment: @Edward I agree it seems a bit awkward at first to put an entirely new row in the table for this, where in a real database you could simply add the tags to the existing observations. However, this *is* the standard way of structuring your data in most stats programs. One nice thing about it is that it makes it trivial to do complex logical subsetting of your data. For example, what if we wanted to make a matrix of histograms for each unique combination of `store` and pizza `type`? This organization allows the slicing for that to be done very easily.